# Azure SQL Does not allow login for Created Clients

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse, azure-sql-managed-instance

I created several users for Azure SQL using the free acccount in a database in Azure Data Studio following the recommended procedure:

- add client ip addresses to firewall
- create login on the master database
- create users
- add appropriate roles that at least encompass db_accessadmin

Despite this, my attempts to login with Azure Data Studio and SSMS continue to fail unless I use the admin account created on setup. The only eror information is:

> Login Failed

I am trying to connect from my ip address and even added my ip address to the database firewall. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

The command run on master to create a user [username and password changed]:

```
CREATE LOGIN userlogin WITH PASSWORD='my_password';
```

The commands run on the database:

```
CREATE USER myuser FROM LOGIN userlogin;
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER myuser;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER myuser;
ALTER ROLE db_accessadmin ADD MEMBER myuser;
```

Details from Azure Data On attempt to access the database:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'myuser'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<TryGetConnection>b__1(Task`1 _)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ReliableConnection.ReliableSqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<<OpenAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ManagedBatchParser\ReliableConnection\ReliableSqlConnection.cs:line 314
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ConnectionService.TryOpenConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ConnectParams connectionParams) in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer\Connection\ConnectionService.cs:line 549
ClientConnectionId:0682c1d3-d252-4379-b0b2-c00364e90356
Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14
```

**EDIT 2**

Well, after some head scratching, I found SSMS. It works like a charm using the same commands. Not sure but the default commands had an *N* before the roles and role user. It also switched *FROM LOGIN* to *FOR LOGIN* I just have up on Azure Data Studio for a while though.

Comment: Does the error come back quickly or is there a pause greater than probably 10 seconds.  How long would you estimate before you are getting the error?  Have you tried with the default user/password created when you create the Azure SQL?

Comment: @Ron The defaults work. It is pretty immediate. I was under the assumption I could have more than 1 user

Comment: You can, just starting with the basics
have you seen this article?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current#examples-1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage

Comment: @Ron yes. that is the thing. I added the login to master and user to the database using the login. even added the ip address to the database firewall but hte error in sys.event_log is login_failed_for_user. I am using the username and password. copied them from the command used to create the user (from notepad)

Comment: can you add the commands to the post?  Of course use fake username and fake password.  Right now you know its not a firewall issue.  If it was the firewall you would have a delay for the error or SSMS would prompt you to add your IP.  If the user is configured and has been given access to the DB.  Then the only thing I can think of is either user doesn't have login permissions or bad password.  Seeing the commands you ran could see if something was missed also allows for testing.

Comment: @Ron added, thx

Comment: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'myuser'.
Is the myuser from the create login line or the create user line?  (probably should have had you only do a fake password since you posed the exception ).  Presuming the myuser was what you created via the create login line.  I probably would just try resetting the password

Comment: @Ron user was supposed to be myuser. i used it on the user database. I brainfarted in find replace. The correct username appears in my actual deployment and was used in the connection attempt.

Comment: In the situation above you are using userlogin in your connection string, and not myuser.   Soryr just wanting to clarify.

CREATE LOGIN userlogin WITH PASSWORD='my_password';
CREATE USER myuser FROM LOGIN userlogin;

Comment: @Ron. Thanks for the help. For some reason, it worked when i used CREATE USER myuser FOR LOGIN instead of FROM LOGIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was you accidentally used FOR instead of From.  Most of the documentation I have seen show that it shouldn't matter.  The only thing I could think of is that if you got the remarks section
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks]

The example explicitly uses from, then there are other references From external providers.  I wonder if there is something that maybe AD wants the From.

**Could just have been a hiccup in the matrix.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Just glad you got it working, and that I was able to help.